# starting at row 2 or 3 UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I wish to start at let's say row 2 with my content. I've tried putting in an integer for indexPath but that doesn't work. 
So in the following example circumference would start at the second row ( and the rest would follow).

http://lh3.ggpht.com/_ixq8Dp4ESMo/SYuylQNqNCI/AAAAAAAAAFk/pPW6pbIlPGo/s576/Screen1.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data source returns a cell when asked for a particular NSIndexPath. You just need to change it so that for the first two rows it returns a null string (@"").

Having said that, doing this kind of seems pointless. If you want to have some blank space at the top of your table there are better ways of doing it (header view for one).

Comment: thnx ... but I wanted to test if I could fill this cell with other content from a different source... anyway thank you for your answer

Comment: Fine, but that's not the question you asked. A table has a single data source. But the datasource is just a class and it can get its data from as many sources as you wish as long as you implement the protocol correctly.